# Reformat datetime object to use slashes instead of dashes

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to normalize a date string: `'6-3-1975'` to a datetime object in this format: `'06/03/1975'`

I have this method:

```
def normalizeDate(date):
    formatted_date = date.replace('-', '/')
    date_obj = datetime.strptime(formatted_date, '%m/%d/%Y').date()
    # date = datetime.strftime(date_obj, '%m/%d/%Y')
    # print(date)
    return date_obj
```

When printing out `.date()` the format uses dashes, I also tried using `strftime` but that would convert the date_object back into a string. Is there a way to reformat the date to use slashes and still be a datetime object?

Answer (score 1):

You can process the date string yourself, to give it the desired format and then convert it to `datetime` object:

```
def normalizeDate(date):
    newDate = '/'.join(str.zfill(elem,2) for elem in date.split('-'))
    date_obj = datetime.strptime(newDate, '%m/%d/%Y').date()
    return date_obj
```

In order to print your date to that specific format, you will have to use `strftime` to the new `datetime` object created:

```
inDate = '6-3-1975'

d = normalizeDate(inDate)
print(d.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
print(type(d))
```

This is the only way to set the format of a `datetime` object.

Comment: Doesn't that still return a string? I'm printing `type(date_obj)` and it indicates it's a string. I need a datetime object since I will be sorting this list of dicts by date.

Comment: @user7496931 you're right. I will edit my answer right away.